# How do I eager load a grandparent record in EF 4.1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using EF4.1 and trying to understand the proper approach to take for eager loading. 
I have an order entry system with a Vendor (grandparent),Purchase Order (parent) and PO2Item (child)  table. The model looks like this [image: ModelScreenImage]

I want to start with a PO2Item record and load the vendor. I thought I could just use **.Include()** like this:

```
var po = (from item in context.PO2Item.Include("PurchaseOrder.Vendor").AsNoTracking()
            where item.OrderLineItemId == lineItem.CostSourceLineItemId
            select item.PurchaseOrder).FirstOrDefault();
```

This does load the PurchaseOrder record but po.Vendor is null. I was reading Julia Lerman's book and Chapter 4 indicated I could use Load but I think 4.1 must have changed this from 4.0 because Load doesn't appear to be defined and there is no such thing as VendorReference. Eventually I dug into the ObjectContext and was able to do this:

```
   if (po!=null)
   {
       context.GetObjectContext().LoadProperty(po, "Vendor");  
   }
```

which does load the Vendor but I have the feeling I'm missing something much simpler. Why doesn't Include("PurchaseOrder.Vendor") work?

### **UPDATE based on Craig's answer.**

Rather than cast the result as an ObjectQuery<> (a cool little trick by itself), I just wrote the query in two stages

```
var links = from link in context.PO2Item.Include("PurchaseOrder.Vendor").AsNoTracking()
            where link.OrderLineItemId == lineItem.CostSourceLineItemId
            select link;

var po_2_item = links.FirstOrDefault();
return po_2_item == null ? null : po_2_item.PurchaseOrder;
```

The returned PO (if one exists) now has the Vendor set properly.

### See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174961/how-do-i-eager-load-a-grandparent-record-in-ef-4-1/8175624#8175624) for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Include()` works on the shape of the returned query.

Your query returns a `PurchaseOrder`, not a `PO2Item`.

You need something more like (Guessing at the types here -- you may be using `DbSet` -- adjust accordingly):

```
var po = ((ObjectQuery<PurchaseOrder>)
         (from item in context.PO2Item
          where item.OrderLineItemId == lineItem.CostSourceLineItemId
          select item.PurchaseOrder))
         .Include("Vendor")
         .AsNoTracking()
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I was missing the important fact that it shapes only the returned item. Using your knowledge I just rewrote it in two steps. I'll modify my question with the new code

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered, but why not just do this?

```
// Get the purchase order (with Vendor) that has the given PO2Item
var po = context.PurchaseOrder.Include("Vendor").AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(
    o => o.PO2Item.Any(i => i.OrderLineItemId == lineItem.CostSourceLineItemId));
```

Comment: Mostly because it didn't occur to me that parameterizing FirstOrDefault() would do this. Good to know, and I do like writing the query starting with the table I'm after, not to mention obviating the need for the null test. Very nice.